# FTP server syncing

Tags: linux, rsync

We have a hosted FTP server.

We want to sync the data over to S3 every week or so.

What would be a good way to do this?

I thought maybe resync but it doesn't work with FTP correct?

What about csync?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to run ssh on the FTP Server?  If so, consider using rsync over ssh.  If you cannot run rsync on the FTP server, but do have the ability to schedule a cron job, you might run a script on the server to build an archive (i.e. tar/gz) on a regular basis, which your remote system cat grab via FTP.